# BizTalk : How to deploy a custom pipe line for all application

Tags: biztalk

When I try to deploy a custom generic receive/send pipe line in Visual Studio. 
I found it deploy to a default BizTalk application not for all applications.

Is there any way we can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot add new artifacts to the System application.  The best you can do is Deploy to a 'shared' Application, then Reference that from any other Application that needs to use that Pipeline.

Comment: How about other application want to configure send/receive port later and want to select the custom pipe line from the list? That means in the design time of other application, they do not want to reference the custom pipe line. They will configure the port and select the pipe line after they deploied.

Comment: Bo Huang: No problem, we do it all the time. You deploy your pipeline to an application, let's call it SharedPipelines. In your other application, MyApp1, you add a reference the SharedPipelines application (in administration console) and you are free to configure the ports to use the pipe line from SharedPipelines.

Comment: Have you even tried this?  There is no relationship between the Design Time (Visual Studio) referencing and BT Admin referencing.  You really wouldn't need to reference the Pipeline project in Visual Studio at all.